# How Does Silicon Surface Barrier (SSB) radiation detectors work?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, photons, semiconductor-physics

I'm dealing whith some old detectors (about 1980) called Silicon Surface Barrier, searching online I've seen that they consist on metal-semiconductor(Si n-type) junction (schottky diode) and in one metal-oxide-semiconductor junction.

I know how these type of junction works and how the depletion layer is formed but I can't undertsand how they work as detectors.

I've to use them like radiation (X-ray) detectors.

Could you please tell me how they work and, just to be sure, if they're really made like I said?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might start at http://www.ortec-online.com/Products-Solutions/RadiationDetectors/silicon-charged-particle-detectors.aspx - Ortec has been making surface barrier detectors basically forever. The linked page has a tutorial on how they are made and operate.  Now, how they work - an energetic particle entering the device will either be charge, or become charge (stripped). Then you get classic Lindhard electronic stopping, which transfers energy to electrons, creating electron-hole pairs, which makes a current pulse for the particle proportional to the energy of the particle.

Comment: thank you, I've already seen the ortec tutorial and it helped a little to figure out the situation!
So these kind of detector act just like a pn-junction one? I was thinking that maybe there were some other mechanism but , in the end, is always a depletion layer.
Ok, so it's only the production of electron-hole pair to make possible to have the signal, thank you again!